# Apply literal type to object in INSERT query

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

In a certain knowledge graph there is a large number of individuals that need
to be assigned a literal token of the type `xsd:token`. It is not practical to
do so manually, therefore I am trying with an `INSERT` instruction. However, I
can't find a way to assign the desired literal type in that kind of query.

Consider in first place this basic example knowledge graph:

```
@prefix : <http://my.example.web/> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .

:1 a foaf:Person ;
    foaf:name "Jane Doe" .

:2 a foaf:Person ;
    foaf:name "John Smith" .
```

The exercise would be to add a token created by removing the blank spaces from
the `foaf:name` literal. For the `:1` this would translate into the addition of the triple:

`:1 dcterms:identifier "JaneDoe"^^xsd:token .`

With a `SELECT` query I can archive it the following
way:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 

SELECT STRDT(?token, xsd:token)
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://my.example.web/> {
        ?s foaf:name ?name .
        BIND(REPLACE(STR(?name)," ","") AS ?token) .
    }
}
```

Which produces the result:

```
LONG VARCHAR
_______________________________________________________________________________

JaneDoe
JohnSmith

2 Rows. -- 54 msec.
```

Now using the same formulation, but with an `INSERT` query:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

INSERT 
{
    GRAPH <http://my.example.web/> {
        ?s dcterms:identifier STRDT(?token, xsd:token) .
    }
}
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://my.example.web/> {
        ?s foaf:name ?name .
        BIND(REPLACE(STR(?name)," ","") AS ?token) .
    }
}
```

An error is the result:

> *** Error 37000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]SQ074: Line 17 (line 17 of "(console)"): SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 9: syntax error at 'STRDT' before '('

In essence I need a way to apply the `STRDT` function to the
object of a triple inside the `INSERT` clause. Or any other alternative mechanism allowing to set a literal type in this kind of query.

Comment: all the creation and binding has to be done in the `WHERE` part. Just put the `STRDT(?token, xsd:token)` into the `BIND` and you're done: `BIND(STRDT(REPLACE(STR(?name)," ",""), xsd:token) AS ?token)` and use the `?token` variable in the `INSERT` part

Comment: @UninformedUser That makes sense, but unfortunately it is not possible to use `STRDT` within the `BIND` function. It invariably returns the error: "SR553: Literal of type xsd:token can not be created from SQL value of type rdf (246): SR066: Unsupported case in CONVERT (VARCHAR -> UNK_DV_TYPE)".

Comment: @UninformedUser Carefully going through the SPARQL specification I reckon your formulation is syntactically correct. Therefore the error I am getting is possibly an internal issue with Virtuoso. If you are able to confirm your solution with another triple store please submit an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your queries are invalid:

```
SELECT STRDT(?token, xsd:token)
```

According to the [`SelectClause`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rSelectClause) production, an expression must be followed by `AS` to give it a variable binding. In essence, you have to use the same syntax you would have used after `BIND` (you also need parentheses around it). As for why Virtuoso accepts this, well Virtuoso does not strictly follow all of SPARQL ‒ it also allows `,` between the variables in `SELECT`, has the `DEFINE` clause, and allows undeclared prefixes if they are recognized by the store.

This is valid:

```
SELECT (STRDT(?token, xsd:token) AS ?tokenTyped)
```

or modify the `BIND`:

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 

SELECT ?token
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://my.example.web/> {
        ?s foaf:name ?name .
        BIND(STRDT(REPLACE(STR(?name)," ",""), xsd:token) AS ?token) .
    }
}
```

This seems the cleanest to me.

Likewise, for the second query, you cannot have an expression as an object of a triple (or any position for that matter), see the [`Object`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rObject) production. Using a variable is the best the syntax allows you to do (while it would certainly be nice to be able to use expressions as you wanted):

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

INSERT 
{
    GRAPH <http://my.example.web/> {
        ?s dcterms:identifier ?token .
    }
}
WHERE {
    GRAPH <http://my.example.web/> {
        ?s foaf:name ?name .
        BIND(STRDT(REPLACE(STR(?name)," ",""), xsd:token) AS ?token) .
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it should work on OpenLink Virtuoso version 07.20.3231. If you have issues with this, perhaps the Virtuoso instance needs to be updated, or refer to [GitHub](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/224).

Comment: As this is the same solution provided by @UninformedUser, for now I will wait for his answer before accepting. I am working with Virtuoso 07.20.3234.